# How to avoid mutex borrowing problems when using it's guard

Tags: rust, mutex

I want my method of struct to perform in a synchronized way. I wanted to do this by using `Mutex` ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=88d6bb960345670385979f25754b6412&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

pub struct A {
    map: BTreeMap<String, String>,
    mutex: Mutex<()>,
}

impl A {
    pub fn new() -> A {
        A {
            map: BTreeMap::new(),
            mutex: Mutex::new(()),
        }
    }
}

impl A {
    fn synchronized_call(&mut self) {
        let mutex_guard_res = self.mutex.try_lock();
        if mutex_guard_res.is_err() {
            return
        }
        let mut _mutex_guard = mutex_guard_res.unwrap(); // safe because of check above
        let mut lambda = |text: String| {
            let _ = self.map.insert("hello".to_owned(),
                                    "d".to_owned());
        };
        lambda("dd".to_owned());
    }
}
```

Error message:

```
error[E0500]: closure requires unique access to `self` but `self.mutex` is already borrowed
  --> <anon>:23:26
   |
18 |         let mutex_guard_res = self.mutex.try_lock();
   |                               ---------- borrow occurs here
...
23 |         let mut lambda = |text: String| {
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ closure construction occurs here
24 |             if let Some(m) = self.map.get(&text) {
   |                              ---- borrow occurs due to use of `self` in closure
...
31 |     }
   |     - borrow ends here
```

As I understand when we borrow anything from the struct we are unable to use other struct's fields till our borrow is finished. But how can I do method synchronization then?

Comment: Could you provide an [MCVE], please? That would help a lot!

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt I have already been doing it :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I edited your answer a bit still, I hope you don't mind. I think in this form it's easier to answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closure needs a mutable reference to the `self.map` in order to insert something into it. But closure capturing works with whole bindings only. This means, that if you say `self.map`, the closure attempts to capture `self`, not `self.map`. And `self` can't be mutably borrowed/captured, because parts of `self` are already immutably borrowed.

We can solve this closure-capturing problem by introducing a new binding for the map alone such that the closure is able to capture it ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9f93ba3b9404f845952028d5d37116a5&version=stable&backtrace=0)):

```
let mm = &mut self.map;
let mut lambda = |text: String| {
    let _ = mm.insert("hello".to_owned(), text);
};
lambda("dd".to_owned());
```

---

**However**, there is something you overlooked: since `synchronized_call()` accepts `&mut self`, you don't need the mutex! Why? *Mutable references* are also called *exclusive references*, because the compiler can assure at compile time that there is only one such mutable reference at any given time.

Therefore **you statically know**, that there is at most one instance of `synchronized_call()` running on one specific object at any given time, *if* the function is not recursive (calls itself).

If you have mutable access to a mutex, you know that the mutex is unlocked. See [the `Mutex::get_mut()` method for more explanation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.get_mut). Isn't that amazing?

Answer (score 4):

Rust mutexes do not work the way you are trying to use them. In Rust, a mutex protects specific data relying on the borrow-checking mechanism used elsewhere in the language. As a consequence, declaring a field `Mutex<()>` doesn't make sense, because it is protecting read-write access to the `()` unit object that has no values to mutate.

As Lukas explained, your `call_synchronized` as declared doesn't need to do synchronization because its signature already requests an exclusive (mutable) reference to `self`, which prevents it from being invoked from multiple threads on the same object. In other words, you need to change the *signature* of `call_synchronized` because the current one does not match the functionality it is intended to provide.

`call_synchronized` needs to accept a shared reference to `self`, which will signal to Rust that it can be called from multiple threads in the first place. Inside `call_synchronized` a call to `Mutex::lock` will simultaneously lock the mutex and provide a mutable reference to the underlying data, carefully scoped so that the lock is held for the duration of the reference:

```
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

pub struct A {
    synced_map: Mutex<BTreeMap<String, String>>,
}

impl A {
    pub fn new() -> A {
        A {
            synced_map: Mutex::new(BTreeMap::new()),
        }
    }
}

impl A {
    fn synchronized_call(&self) {
        let mut map = self.synced_map.lock().unwrap();
        // omitting the lambda for brevity, but it would also work
        // (as long as it refers to map rather than self.map)
        map.insert("hello".to_owned(), "d".to_owned());
    }
}
```